# How to capture last N seconds of packets using tcpdump

Tags: sniffing, tcpdump, delayed-execution

How can I capture the last N seconds of packets using tcpdump?

Comment: "Give me" will not take you far here. Maybe you should show us what you have tried so far and where exactly you have problems you can not solve yourself.

Comment: The bash command you want is: "man tcpdump"

Answer (score 22):

If you just want tcpdump to run for n seconds and then quit, you could use timeout.

For example:

```
timeout 2 tcpdump -eni mon0
```

Otherwise I don't believe tcpdump has an option to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately the timeout command is not present in CentOS 5.x. It was added in a newer release of coreutils. Another motivation for me to upgrade the OS.

Comment: I suppose if you don't have timeout, you could instead create something like timeout with a script:

Comment: Works great for me. I used this to monitor all traffic for a program that wasn't working. I started tcpdump with a timeout of N seconds. Then I started the program (which takes up to N seconds).

Comment: The question asks to capture the *last* N seconds. Your answer tells how to capture the *first* N seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to accomplish this is with tcpdump's -G flag, which, when used with -w, will save your dump to a new file every N seconds.  For instance:

tcpdump -w outfile-%s -G 10

This will create a new file with the name of 'outfile-XXXX' (where XXXX represents the number of seconds since epoch) every 10 seconds.

See the man pages for tcpdump(8) and strftime(3) for additional details.

Comment: tcpdump 3.9.4 as shipped with CentOS 5.10 does not have the -G option. I really need to upgrade my OS.

Comment: -G does not stop the tcpdump command. It still runs forever.
The timeout 2 tcpdump will stop the command after 2 seconds.

Comment: @ciceron: The question wasn't about stopping tcpdump. It was about capturing the *last N seconds*. Your suggestion will capture the *first* N seconds. Decidedly not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tethereal instead of tcpdump.  You can use this command-line option:

```
-a duration:X
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: tcpdump itself doesn't allow for a time-limited packet trace but tshark does.  (n.b. since this question was asked and answered, Ethereal became Wireshark)  `tshark -a duration:600 -i eth0 -w $(hostname).10mins.pcap` will capture ten minutes' worth of traffic from interface eth0 into the file $(hostname).10mins.pcap

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the same issue so,
I wrote a portable script to run tcpdump for n second.

```
#tcpdump_for_n_sec.sh
n=$1
shift #remove first arg from $@ 
tcpdump $@ & x=$!
sleep $n
kill $x
```

Usage ./tcpdump_for_n_sec.sh sec args for tcpdump

```
./tcpdump_for_n_sec.sh 5 -i any not port 22 -s0 -wfile.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

`tcpdump options -w new.tcpdump`

`ps -ef |grep tcpdump`

take note of PID, say it is 11193

`at 11:00
kill 11193`

now just wait til 11:00 comes and your capture will be killed but saved

Comment: fwiw pgrep is a much better alternative to ps|grep; especially here.

Answer (score -1):

sudo tcpdump -i  -w  &
this will run tcpdump is sleeping mode

- w: save output in the .pcap file
  &: tcpdump process will run in sleeping mode
  note: make sure you have enough space available if you want . to run it for a while. It wont interrupt if logoff until you kill the process.